# How to combine one resize and 3 composite commands in one command in imagemagick?

Tags: imagemagick

Currently I have to do:

```
convert src.jpg -resize 600 -quality 70 -colorspace sRGB scaled_images/one.jpg

composite -dissolve 25% -gravity center overlay_image1.png scaled_images/one.jpg   scaled_images/one.jpg

composite -dissolve 60% -gravity southeast overlay_image2.png scaled_images/one.jpg   scaled_images/one.jpg

composite -dissolve 85% -gravity north overlay_image3.png scaled_images/one.jpg   scaled_images/one.jpg
```

Due to multiple cycles of compression/decompression final image quality will suffer.

How can I combine all of above in one command?

I am using imagemagick version  7.0.8-40.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, when using ImageMagick version 7 you should be using the command "magick" instead of "convert". That said, here is an example that should do what you're trying to accomplish in a single command...

```
magick src.jpg -resize 600 -compose dissolve \
   -define compose:args=25 -gravity center overlay1.png -composite \
   -define compose:args=60 -gravity southeast overlay2.png -composite \
   -define compose:args=85 -gravity north overlay3.png -composite \
   -quality 70 one.jpg
```

That starts by reading the input image, resizing it to 600 pixels, and setting the compose method to "dissolve". Then it sets the dissolve amount to 25%, sets the gravity to "center", and composites the first overlay image onto the source. It continues by setting the required dissolve amount and gravity for each successive overlay and composites them onto the results of each previous operation.

End by setting the compression quality for the output JPG and writing the output file. The result will be the source image with multiple overlays, each with differing transparencies and locations, and all done within a single command to avoid degradation through the process.

If you're running on Windows you'll need to change those continued line backslashes "\" to carets "^".

Also note, if you ever do have to save and re-read intermediate files you should not save them in JPG format because there will be a loss of quality with each iteration.

Comment: GeeMack thank u for detailed answer. But the resultant file size is almost 3 times bigger for same quality than if I use 4 separate commands. Strange

Comment: I was expecting smaller size result for same quality when combined into one command

Comment: You have to find the balance between quality and file size you're willing to live with. The smaller file size is probably due to the several rounds of degradation with JPG compression. I'd try the single command I offered and reduce the "-quality N" setting to find an acceptable balance.

Comment: For separate commands saved to JPG are compressing each time. So your final size will be smaller for the same final quality value, since you have done more compression along the way. If you leave off the quality each time, ImageMagick will take the value from the input if available or use 92. But note that you can also use -define jpeg:extent=filesize to achieve some desired file size rather than guessing at some quality value. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/formats/#jpg_write